# Fill arbitrary collection with Integers in Java

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

First question asked, please be understanding to formatting mistakes.

In java, using streams, it's possible to populate some collections with Integers by using `Intstream`,

```
IntStream.range(from,to).boxed().collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
```

Where if you replace `HashSet` with for example `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` you'll simply return that specified collection instead.

Using this, how could you set up a method where you can specify the desired collection interface to populate? What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
public returnType fillWithInt(Class<?> t, int from, int to){
   return IntStream.range(from,to)
       .boxed() 
       .collect(Collectors.toCollection(t::new));
}
```

Trying this I get a warning:

> Class(java.lang.ClassLoader)' has private access in 'java.lang.Class.

I've been on this the whole day and can't figure out what to do.

I might as well say as a disclaimer, I'm very new at programming so I might be tackling this completely wrong. If that's the case I hope to be given a nudge in the right direction!

Comment: Hint: what does [`toCollection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toCollection-java.util.function.Supplier-) expect as parameter type?

Comment: @Holger thank you, I've recognised my uncertainty with Suppliers, I'll go study!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [**method reference**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) cannot be defined using an instance of class as you try to achieve, so you need to implement the `Supplier` of your target `Collection`.

You can do it using **reflection** as next:

```
public <C extends Collection<Integer>> C fillWithInt(Class<C> t, int from, int to) {
    return IntStream.range(from,to)
        .boxed()
        .collect(
            Collectors.toCollection(
                () -> {
                    try {
                        return t.newInstance();
                    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
                    }
                }
            )
        );
}
```

**Example:**

```
Set<Integer> set = fillWithInt(HashSet.class, 1, 10);
```

Or simply by providing the `Supplier` as parameter of your method, as next:

```
public <C extends Collection<Integer>> C fillWithInt(Supplier<C> supplier, 
    int from, int to){
    return IntStream.range(from,to)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(supplier));
}
```

**Example:**

```
Set<Integer> set = fillWithInt(HashSet::new, 1, 10);
```

Comment: Note that it doesn’t work in the Reflection variant as you can’t have a `Class<HashSet<Integer>>`. `HashSet.class` will have the type `Class<HashSet>` refering to the raw `HashSet` type. This isn’t solvable, so it’s good that we don’t need it under Java 8 anymore.